# Why are the commands implemented by a custom module still listed after uninstalling it?

Tags: 8, console

I registered a new command via Drupal Console using `drupal generate:command`. I associated the command with a custom module, but after uninstalling the module and removing the module folder, the command still appears when issuing a `drupal list` command. I couldn't find anything in the Drupal Console documentation relating to this.

How do I let Drupal Console know my module is being uninstalled, so that it doesn't list its commands anymore? Does the module needs to implement a specific method for that, or do I need to run a Drupal Console command for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Issuing `drupal module:uninstall my_module` removes the command from the Drupal Console command list.